# Switched from shared library to dll, now getting an error that it can't find pow()

Tags: c, math, undefined, symbols, pow

Here is the error:

```
symbol lookup error: ./src/libprog3.so: undefined symbol: pow
```

Everything else in the library works fine, even functions that use math.h, but when I call the function that needs pow(), it crashes. It worked perfectly fine when it was a shared library. I am using gcc and a makefile to compile. The only change I made to the makefile was adding -ldl for the library. I still have -lm in it. I changed the driver program to support the change to the dll instead of the shared library, but the function causing the error hasn't changed.

Is there more to the makefile that I need to change?
Here is the makefile:

```
testlib: src/driver.o src/prog3.o
    gcc -fPIC -Wall -c src/prog3.c -o src/prog3.o
    gcc -Wall -shared -o src/libprog3.so src/prog3.o
    gcc -Wall -o $@ src/driver.c -ldl -lm -Lsrc -lprog3
```

Comment: All you did was add `-ldl` to the last line in the the example makefile snippet?  So if you remove `-ldl` it works again?  I feel like we're missing some important information.

Comment: I changed it from a shared library to a dynamic loaded library. I made a lot of changes to the driver program and added the -ldl to the Makefile. Removing the -ldl now would give me a lot of errors in driver.c. I was thinking that the error wasn't in driver.c, since the library is the one causing the error.

Comment: Also, do you mean: "switched from *static* library to dll"?  "Shared library" and "dll" mean the same thing to me.

Comment: I mean from shared to to dll. So that the libraries are linked and loaded at runtime and only if the driver program call them, instead of the entire library being loaded if only certain modules are needed.

Comment: Let's get some terminology straight: DLL (*dynamic-link library*) is a Windows term; the corresponding term for non-Windows OSes is *shared library* or equivalently *shared object*.  They refer to the same thing (a piece of code that can be simultaneously loaded into multiple processes at once, hence the *shared*) in different contexts.  GCC's `-shared` option creates a shared object.  Linking with the dynamic linker (`-ldl`) does not change an object file's sharedness.

Comment: I meant a dynamically loaded library, but in Linux. I confused the acronyms. However, any help on the question would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be doing:

```
gcc -Wall -shared -o src/libprog3.so src/prog3.o -lm
```

That is, shared libraries must be built with their dependencies. If you omit the `-lm`, you're telling the linker that unresolved symbols in `libprog3.so` are intended to be resolved by symbols in the main program or libraries it has already caused to be loaded. I see you did put `-lm` on the link command line for the main program, but my guess is that the main program did not actually use any symbols from `libm.so` and thus it did not get added to the `DT_NEEDED` table for the main program and therefore is not already loaded.

In any case, making dependencies explicit like this is almost always best.

Comment: I actually tried that earlier and it didn't work, but I tried it again and now it works. I guess I had another thing wrong I fixed on the way. Before stopped thinking it was the problem because it worked before I made the dynamic links. Thank you!